# Mongodb chunksize issue

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection which have size : 60 GB

I want to shard this collection. Shard key is hash index and unique.

I followed this document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sharding-Existing-Collection-Data-Size

Avg byte size of shard key values 56287232

maxCollectionSize is coming 9.28 GB

As maxCollectionSize and Actual collection size different is huge i am unable to get what chunk size should i use

Thanks for help

Comment: ,What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [Modify Chunk Size in a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/modify-chunk-size-in-sharded-cluster/) The default chunk size for a sharded cluster is **`64`** megabytes.

As MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) `New in version 2.6`: MongoDB provides the `mergeChunks` command to combine contiguous chunk ranges into a single chunk. See [Merge Chunks in a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/merge-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) for more information.

**Note:** Be careful when splitting data in a sharded collection to create new chunks. When you shard a collection that has existing data, MongoDB automatically creates chunks to evenly distribute the collection. To split data effectively in a sharded cluster you must consider the number of documents in a chunk and the average document size to create a uniform chunk size. When chunks have irregular sizes, shards may have an equal number of chunks but have very different data sizes. Avoid creating splits that lead to a collection with differently sized chunks.

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem. Because you are using hashed sharding index (64bits), calculation goes:

```
16777216 (bytes)/8 (bytes) = 2097152 maxSplits
2097152 * (64MB/2)=67'108'864MB = 65'536GB = 64TB
```

So, you will get about 1000 chunks what is distributed evenly to all shards in the cluster.